# Generic type constrain for ValueType in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, where-clause

I have generic class that restricts arguments to use `int` or `long` types. My issue that I need to compare variables of this argument type in my method. But compiler said that I can't compare these items -

> *Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'K' and 'K'*

My code:

```
public class MyClass<T,K>
    where T : Entity<K>
    //where K : ??? - what can I do?
{
    public virtual bool MyMethod(T entity1, T entity2)
    {
        return entity1.EntityId == entity2.EntityId;//Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'K' and 'K'
    }
}
public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    public T EntityId{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: as your title says value type constraints can be specified by using struct keyword but it would not solve the compilation error.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Yeah, you are right, I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can constraint `K` on [`IEquatable<K>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use `Equals`:

```
public class MyClass<T,K>
    where T : Entity<K>
    where K : IEquatable<K>
{
    public virtual bool MyMethod(T entity1, T entity2)
    {
        return entity1.EntityId.Equals(entity2.EntityId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before posting - without success.

Comment: @RredCat What does "without success" mean?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the `==` operator, you can always use the static [`object.Equals(object, object)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

That object will invoke the - possibly overridden - [`Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of whatever is passed to it, which, for value types, should be implemented to support value equality.

So, your method could be written like this:

```
public virtual bool MyMethod(T entity1, T entity2)
{
    return object.Equals(entity1.EntityId, entity2.EntityId);
}
```

You wouldn't need an extra constraint, and in fact, it would even still work in some way if `T` were a reference type.